# Proving existence and uniqueness of a matrix,

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let A be nxn with real coefficients and assume that it has n distinct eigenvalues, and all eigenvalues are positive real numbers.

Let k $\ge$3 be an odd integer.

a) Prove there exists a unique real matrix B with $B^k$ = A.

b) How many complex matrices B satisfy $B^k$ = A.  (Include the real matrices B in your count.)

I would like hints only.

I know, from my previous questions on MSE, that positive real eigenvalues does *not* imply A is symmetric, and hence not necessarily positive-definite.

I also know that A is diagonalizable (not necessarily orthogonally diagonalizable), because of the n distinct eigenvalues it has - so $$A = SDS^{-1}$$,

where S's columns are eigenvectors of A.

...now I need to somehow make use of the other information given, namely that the eigenvalues are positive and real.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $B$ is diagonalized by the same $S$.

Comment: Thanks, Professor Israel.  It is $SD^\frac{1}{k}S^{-1}$, and to check uniqueness, we need only check that D^(1/k) is unique, but the diagonal entries are unique for k odd, since we look at the relation between B and A's eigenvalues and solve $x_{ii}^\frac{1}{k} = d_{ii}$.    Can you offer a hint for part (b)?  Seems strange that after we've established that there is a unique B that now we are asked to count many more (complex) matrices that satisfy $B^k = A$.  Thanks,

Comment: Instead of the positive $k$'th root, use ...

Comment: complex k'th roots :-).  Thanks so much, Professor Israel - have a great night!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- $B$ is diagonalized by the same $S$.
- The entries of $D$ correspond to the eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Thanks, @bashfuloctopus.  Can you offer a hint for part(b)? :-)